# maven multi module data aggregator

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, multi-module

I have a requirement to develop a maven plugin which basically has to do the following.

The multi module project structure looks like this,

**SampleProject**

```
-  Module X
    o   Review (a folder)
           x.xml
    o   Pom.xml
-  Module Y
    o   Review 
           Y.xml
    o   Pom.xml
-  Module Z
    o   Review 
           z.xml
    o   Pom.xml
-  Pom.xml (aggregate pom)
```

**Aggregate POM**

```
<modules>
    <module>Module X</module>
    <module> Module Y </module>
    <module> Module XZ</module>
   </modules>
```

The review folder in each of the modules has XML files. Now, the plugin should count the number of certain entries in those XMLs and generate the text file with the count details. The text file should be generated for each and every module with the count for that specific module. Also, there should a text file generated with the total count of all the modules (cummulative report). I got this working but the plugin runs for all the modules once and then runs at the root level which scans through all the modules again for such XMLs. I need a way to get the total count from the counts of every module already avaialable. I dont want the process to happen again. 
I tried with the @aggregator but it does not seem to help.

Are there any better solutions?